# Multiply numbers from different data frames based on all the possible combinations

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have 5 data frames like the ones below:

```
df_mon <- data.frame(mon = as.factor(c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
                   number = c(1.11, 1.02, 0.95, 0.92, 0.72))

df_year <- data.frame(year = as.factor(c(1, 2)),
                   number = c(1.61, 0.4))

df_cat <- data.frame(cat = c("A", "B", "C"),
                   number = c(1.11, 1.02, 0.44))

df_bin <- data.frame(bin = as.factor(c(1, 2)),
                      number = c(1.42, 0.56))

df_cat2 <- data.frame(cat2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "AA"),
                     number = c(0.11, 1.22, 1.34, 0.88, 0.75))
```

I need to multiple all the numbers in the 'number' columns from each of these data frames with each other. So, look at all the possible combinations in the first column in each data set and then take the number and multiple them. The final results data frame should look something like this (First 3 are done)

```
results_df <- data.frame(combi = c("mon6_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A", "mon6_year1_catA_bin1_cat2B",  "mon6_year1_catA_bin1_cat2C"),
                       final_number = c(1.11*1.61*1.11*1.42*0.11, 1.11*1.61*1.11*1.42*1.22, 1.11*1.61*1.11*1.42*1.34))
```

We can see the first column in the the `results_df` shows what combination was used to calculate the `final_number`. The first example shows, the `'number'` column from `mon_df cat 6` (1.11) is taken and multiplied with the following:

- category 1 (1.61) from df_year
- category A (1.11) from df_cat
- category 1 (1.42) from df_bin
- category A (0.11) from df_cat2

The answer for this combination is 1.11 x 1.61 x 1.11 x 1.42 x 0.11 = 0.3098.
The 2nd row shows the next possible combination and so on.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `expand.grid` like below

```
lst <- list(df_mon, df_year, df_cat, df_bin, df_cat2)
results_df <- data.frame(
  combi = do.call(
    paste,
    c(do.call(
      expand.grid,
      lapply(lst, function(v) paste0(names(v[1]), v[, 1]))
    ), sep = "_")
  ),
  final_number = Reduce(
    "*",
    do.call(
      expand.grid,
      lapply(lst, `[[`, 2)
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
> head(results_df)
                        combi final_number
1  mon6_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.30985097
2  mon7_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.28472792
3  mon8_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.26518777
4  mon9_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.25681342
5 mon10_year1_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.20098441
6  mon6_year2_catA_bin1_cat2A   0.07698161
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
df_all <- df_mon %>%
  full_join(df_year, by = character()) %>%  # by = character() ensures cross join
  full_join(df_cat, by = character()) %>%
  full_join(df_bin, by = character()) %>%
  full_join(df_cat2, by = character()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-mon, -year, -cat, -bin, -cat2)) %>%
  group_by(mon, year, cat, bin, cat2) %>%
  summarize(final_number = prod(value), .groups = "keep")
# A tibble: 300 x 6
# Groups:   mon, year, cat, bin, cat2 [300]
   mon   year  cat   bin   cat2  final_number
   <fct> <fct> <chr> <fct> <chr>        <dbl>
 1 6     1     A     1     A            0.310
 2 6     1     A     1     AA           2.11 
 3 6     1     A     1     B            3.44 
 4 6     1     A     1     C            3.77 
 5 6     1     A     1     D            2.48 
 6 6     1     A     2     A            0.122
 7 6     1     A     2     AA           0.833
 8 6     1     A     2     B            1.36 
 9 6     1     A     2     C            1.49 
10 6     1     A     2     D            0.978
# ... with 290 more rows
```

It keeps the variables from the other data.frames intact as columns for further analysis, but you could create your `combi` column with a little `paste()`.

Comment: Very helpful and i love the tidy solutions, they're easy to follow. However, I tried this solution but it didn't work. I get this error: Error: `by` must specify variables to join by

Comment: I am using `dplyr` version 1.0.1.  Having `by = character()` might be new behavior if you are still using 0.8 or earlier.

Comment: Yes i was on a older version of dplyr. Works all fine, thanks :)